# MacFamilyTree 8 how to design book cover?

Tags: publishing, macfamilytree

I use [MacFamilyTree](http://www.syniumsoftware.com/macfamilytree) 8.0.10. and cannot find a possibility to design the book cover, so that I can add the picture as a background and maybe change the font type and sizes, such as [this](https://www.canva.com/templates/) random templates show.

I know that I can add a picture but I cannot insert it as background

Do you know if this is possible (or going to be in near future)?